# Enabling GSO for tuntap interfaces seems to slow down traffic

Tags: c, linux, performance, networking, tun-tap

I've been encountering relatively disappointing performances relating to an in-house made vpn.

| Interface | speed Mb/s |
| --- | --- |
| enp5s0 | 950 |
| tun0 | 550 |

And I came to believe the culprit (among some others) to be TCP segmentation (see [this article](https://tailscale.com/blog/throughput-improvements)).

The thing is, linux networking is not my specialty and I feel a bit out of my depth, I'm not so sure to understand how GSO works, what it needs or even that is indeed what I'm looking for (I hope not to fall prey to a XY problem).

I will be using [simpletun](https://github.com/gregnietsky/simpletun) by [Homer Simpson](https://github.com/gregnietsky) as a case study.

I'm open for alternative, but I'm mainly asking about the proper way to enable GSO between a TUN interface to offload forward segmentation as late as possible (that I understand to be advantageous as far as performances are concerned).

The question concerns networking on linux. I'm not concerned with interoperability with any other OS for the time being.

## Expanding on the problem

### documenting

I've been having a hard time finding proper documentation on this feature. For the time being, I've only been able to find

- [this function in the tuntap driver regarding ioctl calls](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/f443e374ae131c168a065ea1748feac6b2e76613/drivers/net/tun.c#L2980)
- [this function regarding setting offload options](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/f443e374ae131c168a065ea1748feac6b2e76613/drivers/net/tun.c#L2803)
- [these notes relating to tuntap options](https://ldpreload.com/p/tuntap-notes.txt)
- [the header file if_tun.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6d280f4d760e3bcb4a8df302afebf085b65ec982/include/uapi/linux/if_tun.h)
- [The official docs on the tuntap driver](https://docs.kernel.org/networking/tuntap.html)

### What I did

I added the ifr flag `IFF_VNET_HDR` as explained in some of the sources given
I added one ioctl call, and another to set what I think are the correct flag for offloading forward

- F_CSUM : to disable checksum
- F_TS04, F_TSO6 : to enable tcp segmentation fault

```
/**************************************************************************
 * tun_alloc: allocates or reconnects to a tun/tap device. The caller     *
 *            must reserve enough space in *dev.                          *
 **************************************************************************/
int tun_alloc(char *dev, int flags) {

  struct ifreq ifr;
  int fd, err;
  char *clonedev = "/dev/net/tun";

  if( (fd = open(clonedev , O_RDWR)) < 0 ) {
    perror("Opening /dev/net/tun");
    return fd;
  }

  memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));

  // flags = 0x0001 ≡ IFF_TUN
  // flag IFF_VNET_HDR necessary ?
  ifr.ifr_flags = flags | IFF_NO_PI | IFF_VNET_HDR;

  if (*dev) {
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, dev, IFNAMSIZ);
  }

  if( (err = ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *)&ifr)) < 0 ) {
    perror("ioctl(TUNSETIFF)");
    close(fd);
    return err;
  }


  // setting up offload
  unsigned long offload_flags = TUN_F_CSUM | TUN_F_TSO4 | TUN_F_TSO6;

  if ( (err = ioctl(fd, TUNSETOFFLOAD, offload_flags)) < 0 ) {
    perror("ioctl(TUNSETOFFLOAD)");
    close(fd);
    return err;
  }
  // --------------------------------------------------------------

  strcpy(dev, ifr.ifr_name);

  return fd;
}
```

### Expected results

I expected the vpn to gain performances because of offloading.

### results obtained

It resulted in being slightly slower. results obtained with iperf3

| Interface | speed Mb/s |
| --- | --- |
| enp5s0 | 942 |
| tun0 | 324 |

This is confusing to me, I could understand a specific error but I do not understand how I could end up with slower results.

## Annexes

### iperf3

```
> iperf3 -c $SERVER_IP
Connecting to host 192.168.50.112, port 5201
[  5] local 192.168.30.175 port 53126 connected to 192.168.50.112 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec   114 MBytes   952 Mbits/sec    0    529 KBytes       
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec   113 MBytes   949 Mbits/sec    0    557 KBytes       
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec   112 MBytes   939 Mbits/sec    0    617 KBytes       
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec   111 MBytes   933 Mbits/sec    0    747 KBytes       
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec    0    783 KBytes       
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec    0    783 KBytes       
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec   111 MBytes   933 Mbits/sec    0    820 KBytes       
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec    0    909 KBytes       
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec    0    909 KBytes       
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec   111 MBytes   933 Mbits/sec    0    953 KBytes       
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.10 GBytes   942 Mbits/sec    0             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.09 GBytes   939 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

```
> iperf3 -B 10.10.9.1%tun0 -c $SERVER_IP
Connecting to host 192.168.50.112, port 5201
[  5] local 10.10.9.1 port 52443 connected to 192.168.50.112 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec   107 KBytes   879 Kbits/sec   20   2.83 KBytes       
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  45.2 KBytes   371 Kbits/sec   10   4.24 KBytes       
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  41.0 KBytes   336 Kbits/sec   10   5.66 KBytes       
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  39.6 KBytes   324 Kbits/sec    8   4.24 KBytes       
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  39.6 KBytes   324 Kbits/sec   10   5.66 KBytes       
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  39.6 KBytes   324 Kbits/sec   10   5.66 KBytes       
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  79.2 KBytes   649 Kbits/sec    8   7.07 KBytes       
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  39.6 KBytes   324 Kbits/sec   10   5.66 KBytes       
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  39.6 KBytes   324 Kbits/sec   11   1.41 KBytes       
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  39.6 KBytes   324 Kbits/sec    9   2.83 KBytes       
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec   510 KBytes   418 Kbits/sec  106             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.08  sec   431 KBytes   351 Kbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```